# Merging two columns, but changing the name of specific variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I have two factor columns with a number of missing data. The names of specific variables were changed during data collection. What I am trying to do is merge the two columns together, but change the names of specific old variables to match the new.

I used

```
help <- data.frame(var1 = c("red", "", "blue", "", "red", "orange", "", "", "red"),
                   var2 = c("", "lightred", "blue", "lightred", "", "", "", "", ""))
```

To create

```
> help
    var1     var2
1    red         
2        lightred
3   blue     blue
4        lightred
5    red         
6 orange         
7                
8                
9    red
```

and am hoping for

```
> help
    var1     var2   newvar
1    red          lightred
2        lightred lightred
3   blue     blue     blue
4        lightred lightred
5    red          lightred
6 orange            orange
7                         
8                         
9    red          lightred
```

So for the purposes of this example, merging the variables into `newvar` and changing the name of the variable `red` to `lightred`. I have a number of variables to change, but think I'll be able to troubleshoot the rest if I can get it to work with one.

Update: Close to a solution here thanks to @Veerendra Gadekar....

I used the below code

`help$newvar= gsub('red', 'lightred', help$var1)`

but the variables `lightred` did not transfer over to `newvar`... the output is below

```
    var1     var2   newvar
1    red          lightred
2        lightred         
3   blue     blue     blue
4        lightred         
5    red          lightred
6 orange            orange
7                         
8                         
9    red          lightred
```

thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if that's the correct logic, but try sth in the veins of `transform(help, newvar = ifelse(var1 == "red", "lightred", ifelse(var1 == "", as.character(var2), as.character(var1))))`.

Comment: `help$newvar= gsub('red', 'lightred', help$var1)`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar: You solution is excellent since it effectively side-steps the problems created by the factor levels being different. I'd suggest you post as an answer.

Comment: @lukeA is there a way to run your transform code with variables that are integers... however for rows with missing data, preserve the NA versus changing them to 0's. When I run your code but replace as.character with as.integer, it replaces the NAs to 0s, but I want to keep them as NAs.

Comment: @bpace Add an example, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using gsub()

```
 help$newvar= gsub('red', 'lightred', help$var1)
```

if you have multiple elements to replace then you can do something like this

```
# for instance

to.replace = c('red', 'blue')

replace.with = c('lightred', 'lightblue')

for(i in 1:length(to.replace)){
   help$newvar[i] = gsub(to.replace[i], replace.with[i], help$var1[i])}
```

Comment: that is close, but unfortunately, the lightred variables in var2 do not transfer to newvar... I added the output from help$newvar= gsub('red', 'lightred', help$var1)

Comment: I am not very sure if you are looking for this, `help$newvar = ifelse(help$newvar == '', as.character(help$var2), help$newvar)`. If this does not give the desirable output, then I would suggest you to show how the output should look like

Comment: thanks for the continued help with this. when I use the ifelse command, the `help$newvar` works with the above fake data, but when I run this with my larger dataset, `newvar` comes back as an integer. any thoughts on why this might be? the structure of the data is exactly the same for both the real and fake dataset. i'm completely stumped.